# Under what conditions do I need to single quote a variable in a Mysql statement in PHP?

Tags: mysql

Under what conditions do I need to single quote a variable in a Mysql statement in PHP?

Comment: If you use parametrized arguments, you don't need to quote at all... plus you get some other nice benefits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put values directly in the query, as in `SELECT * FROM users WHERE age > 25`, then the single quotes are used only with strings. If you write `SELECT * FROM users WHERE age > '25'`, the query works the same, but you are forcing MySQL to convert the string to an integer (if that field is an integer), which is a not necessary operation.

Answer (score 1):

In theory only varchars, texts, and BLOBs I think, but I say quote `em all. That has nothing to do with PHP by the way but only with the way you build your mySQL query, unless you mean something completely different.

Comment: yeah, I too wrap every variable with single quote, be it varchar, text, int, boolean. It's just my personal preferences

Comment: Also dates generally need to be quoted (except for unix style timestamps of course)

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer, but I suggest a database class like Zend DB to interact with your database. I have found this to be a great way to abstract away some of the grunt work like figuring out what to do with variables.

For example:

```
$db->select()->from('users', array('uid'))->where('email = ?', $indata['email'])->where('actkey = 0')
```

Makes a cleaner query than building the same by hand, and also takes care of making those variables safe a lot better than I would.

Hope that's helpful info.